# Backbone - check if row returned and loaded to model

Tags: backbone.js

I have a model called game. In the router I do:

```
            var game = new models.Game({game_id:game_id,team_id:team_id});
            game.fetch({
              success: function (data) {
                    slider.slidePage(new Game({model:data}).$el);
                }
           });
```

Then in the Game view I want to determine if the database returned anything. What's the best way to do this? At moment I have:

```
    initialize: function (options) {
       if(this.model){
           console.log('in the if');
       }
       else{
           console.log('in the else');
       }
    }
```

But this will always go into the if even if no row is returned from the database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you would want to check for the `id` property, which in theory only the server should know.  (Or, check for a required property like name using `Model.has("game_name")`.)

```
if(typeof this.model.id != "undefined") {
       console.log('in the if');
   }
```

Alternatively, you might want to consider having the server return an HTTP code like "404 not found", to indicate no data.  That way, you could be sure that the `success` callback will always have data, and handle the no-data scenario in the `error` callback.

Comment: Yes I thought about this but I thought there may be a more elegant way of doing it. But this will do fine:)

Comment: @user1716672 you're right - I updated my answer.  I think checking for `id` is good, because that implies a successful database read on the server.

Comment: actually, weirdly, if(this.model.id != "undefined") is always returning true even if this.model.id is undefined. But if(this.model.id) performs correctly

Comment: @user1716672 type conversion is a bit iffy in Javascript - I think you're supposed to use `typeof this.model.id != "undefined"` to be safe.